# Get a hold on the element of the current iteration inside a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple `v-for` for rendering a list of spans:

```
<span v-for="kc in kcList">
    {{ kc }}
</span>
```

In each iteration, I would like to be able to get a grab on the span and add an onclick function to it that alerts the value of kc let's say

How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much exactly like you describe, although I don't know what you mean by "get a grab on". You just put a click handler on the span to call a method that does the alert.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    kcList: ['one','two','three']
  },
  methods: {
    alertOn(kc) {
      alert(kc);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-for="kc in kcList" @click="alertOn(kc)">
    {{ kc }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add an `onclick` only on certain of these spans (with a condition depending on the value of kc)

Comment: on the method "alertOn" that @Roy J just created, you can make your condition, and check what ever you want to check